# Is dividng a float by an int faster than vice versa?

Tags: floating-point, precision

In mathematics, there is a bias against having square roots in the denominators of expression. This comes from before the computer age, when you would have to calculate an expression like 1/sqrt(2) by hand, which is annoying since sqrt(2) is a long decimal which you have to cutoff at some point, which makes the error worse. Doing the equivalent calculation sqrt(2)/2 is much easier to do by hand, and the error you get from approximating sqrt(2) isn't as bad. This bias is still taught in schools (mostly due to inertia) even though the reasoning for it doesn't really hold anymore. But my question is, do computers care (since they're doing these calculations for us now)? Is one of those calculations faster/easier than the other in a typical language/architecture? I guess the precision issues still hold, but for simple calculations, they're irrelevant. A dollar-store calculator is capable of computing sqrt(2) to more precision than most people will ever need, so algorithmic concerns are the only ones that seem important.

Comment: Your title asks about `float` and `int`, which are commonly used to refer to **types**, meaning specific ways of representing values using patterns of bits. However, your question seems to ask about integer and non-integer **values**. When calculating `1 / sqrt(2)` or `sqrt(2) / 2`, both the numerator and the denominator would be held in a floating-point format when the division is performed. You should clarify what you are asking.

Comment: By and large, manipulating an expression to make a denominator an integer value will have little or no effect on accuracy or performance. There are some exceptions—when using a floating-point format that uses base two, dividing by a power of two will introduce no error (within the range of the format). Such concerns are minor, even negligible, in most situations but may be considered when particular attention is being paid to accuracy.

Comment: So, your first comment suggests that maybe my question is kind of nonsense. Because down in the bits, it's either 1.0000000000000... / 1.414..................  or 1.414..................../2.0000............., so they'll be equivalent calculations either way. Is that correct?

Comment: Computer processors commonly have different formats for floating-point types and integer types and even keep floating-point data in different registers than integer data. In many processors, if we want to divide a floating-point type by an integer type, we have to move the integer to floating-point registers and convert it to the floating-point format, then perform the division. So, if you are asking about types, it is often better to work solely in floating-point types, not to mix them with integer types. If you are asking about values, then it mostly does not matter.

Comment: Note that compilers will optimize expressions in many circumstances. If you write `x/3`, where `x` is a `double`, a decent compiler will write the `double` form of three into the program. It will not write an integer three into the program along with instructions to convert it to floating-point before the division. However, if you write `x/y`, where `x` is a `double` and `y` is an `int`, the compiler may have to write instructions into the program to convert `y` to a `double`, because it may have no way to do the conversion in  advance.